# Typewriter Function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the first code block output is just 'T' repeated but the second block of code works? 
First code block:

```
function typeWriter() {
  var i = 0,
  txt = 'Testing',
  speed = 40,
  typed = document.getElementById('typewriter');

  (function addChar() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      typed.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  })();
} 

document.onload = typeWriter();
```

Second code block:

```
var i = 0,
  txt = 'Testing',
  speed = 40;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code block, each call of typeWriter() sets i=0, so you always get 'T'. In the second, i is defined outside of typeWriter(), so it's value persists between calls.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out too and I need to call the inner function in the setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block you wanted to call `typeWriter()` over and over again until `i >= txt.length`. But what you actually doing is: whenever you call `typeWriter()` the first line `var i = 0` is called and resets `i` to `0`. If you want it to work as you wish you just need to define `i` outside the function and it should look like the 2nd block